# Trying to use hierarchical select in exposed view filter - dont get the option

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have activated the Hierarchical select taxonomy views module, but when I add an exposed filter on my taxonomy term, I dont get an option to use the hierarchical select as a widget as the documentation says I should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Simple Hierachical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) module instead which works

> Simple hierarchical select defines a new form widget for taxonomy
>   fields to select a term by "browsing" through the vocabularies
>   hierarchy.